# Referencing to a cell in a notebook from ipython notebook

Tags: ipython

I'm building a tutorial notebook, and I want the first cell to act as a TOC, linking to other cells in the notebook. so you could read the header, click a link and get to the cell of interest. Is this possible?

I searched this questions and came up with nothing, so it must be super trivial... :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On master (1.0.dev) heading cell have an anchor if you click on it that you can reference. (only header cells) you can also have a look at [this](https://github.com/minrk/ipython_extensions/blob/master/nbtoc.py)

Comment: Thanks. I can now see the flaoting box of "Contents" in my notebook, but it is empty. I checked my ipython version and it is:
'0.13.2'

also, i dont see the anchor symbols you were talking about. so my guess is that in not in 1.0 dev? What should i do from here?

Comment: 0.13.2 is one year old. if yo want anchor you will have to install newer version in dev, or wait for stable.

Comment: Got it. I might need some help installing it.. I saw that i need to install git in order to install the development version. I succedded installing it, but i'm stock trying to use it to install the dev version. The command im suppose to use is "$ git clone https://github.com/ipython/ipython.git" but i dont understand the $ sign and typing the command on cmd or ipthon shell did not work. what am i doing wrong? Im on windows..

Comment: Hi Matt, is it possible to link from a simple markdown cell within the notebook to other Chapter in the notebook (Chapter cell is header cell)?

Comment: Haven't tested, but `[link](other.ipynb#header-anchor)` should work on 1.0 and above. On 2.0 you can also go into subdirectory. If in the same notebook you can just drop `other.ipynb`.

Comment: Worked on the same notebook, great!